# How do I find the infinite sum of $\arctan(2^{-n})$?

Tags: computer-science

I am looking at the CORDIC Algorithm and I want to show that iterative rotations by the nth angle given by arctan $2^{-n}$ is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \arctan 2^{-n}
$$

Comment: Please type and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you can try to compare $\arctan 2^{-n}$ to some other progression, that involves $\pi$. Perhaps compare it to $\pi/2^{n+2}$

Comment: The title of your question is a bit misleading in that we don't have a closed form recipe for that sum. IIRC it is a precalculated constant that CORDIC uses. You only need to estimate it. Check out Matti's hint :-)

Comment: Well $\;\displaystyle \arctan(2^{-n})>2^{-n}-\frac{8^{-n}}3$ so that your sum will be [over $\;\displaystyle\frac {34}{21}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%282%5E%28-n%29-8%5E%28-n%29%2F3%2Cn%3D0..infinity%29) that is over $\;\displaystyle\frac {\pi}2$.

Answer (score 4):

By the strict concavity of $\tan^{-1}(x)$, for $0\lt x\lt1$
$$
\tan^{-1}(x)\gt\frac\pi4x\tag1
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2^k}\right)
&=\frac\pi4+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2^k}\right)\tag{2a}\\
&\gt\frac\pi4+\frac\pi4\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac\pi2\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\frac \pi 4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$
Using Taylor expansion
$$\tan^{-1}( t) = \sum _{p=0}^{\infty } (-1)^p\frac{t^{2 p+1}}{2p+1} \qquad \forall  t \in~ ]-1,1[,$$
and Fubini's theorem, one gets
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\sum _{p=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^p}{\left(2^{2 p+1}-1\right) (2 p+1)}$$ which converge very fast since
$$a_p=\frac{1}{\left(2^{2 p+1}-1\right) (2 p+1)} \quad\implies \quad\underset{p\to \infty }{\text{limit}}\left(\frac{a_{p+1}}{a_p}  \right)=\frac 14.$$
The series $\sum_p (-1)^p/((2p+1)(2^{2p+1}-1))$ fulfills the conditions of the alternating series test, so the partial sums
$$1,\frac{20}{21},\frac{3121}{3255},\frac{395902}{413385},\frac{123888
   89}{12933045},\frac{278947680568}{291213374265},\cdots.$$
are larger than $\frac{20}{21} >\frac \pi 4$ and then the full summation larger than $\frac \pi 2$.

**Edit**

Faster would be to use
$$\tan^{-1}( t) > \frac{3 t}{3+t^2} \qquad \forall  t >0$$
$$3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ 2^{-n}}{3+2^{-2 n}}=$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2 \log (2)}+i\,\frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2 \log (2)}\left(\psi _2^{(0)}\left(\frac{\log (12)+i \pi}{2log (2)}\right)-\psi
   _2^{(0)}\left(\frac{\log (12)-i \pi}{2\log (2)}\right)\right)$$ which is $0.955696 > \frac \pi 4$.